# rake でクラスメソッドを切り出したい

Tags: ruby, rake

以下のような Rakefile を記述しました。

```
class HogeUtility
  def self.hoge
    sh "echo hoge"
  end
end

desc "Test task"
task "hogeTest" do
  HogeUtility.hoge
end
```

実際にこのタスクを実行してみたところ、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
$ rake hogeTest
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `sh' for HogeUtility:Class
/home/vagrant/Workspace/verify-tester/Rakefile:5:in `hoge'
/home/vagrant/Workspace/verify-tester/Rakefile:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => hogeTest
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

どうしたら、クラスメソッドとして切り出した処理を実行できますか？

なぜ、クラスメソッドして切り出したいか、というと、複数別々のタスクからその処理を実行したいからです。なので、クラスメソッドでなくても、処理が切り出せればいいとは思っています。

Comment: https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler/issues/181#issuecomment-1229131 辺りを見ると、`include Rake::DSL` を追加するか、`sh` の代わりに `Kernel::system()` を使う対応方法がある様です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rake::DSL` を extend すれば実現できました。

```
module HogeUtility
  extend Rake::DSL
  def self.hoge
    sh "echo hoge"
  end
end

desc "Test task"
task "hogeTest" do
  HogeUtility.hoge
end
```

実行例:

```
$ rake hogeTest
echo hoge
hoge
```